# Pandas Df logical expression for Not In

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am converting java code into a python for re-writing an legacy etl application. In my legacy application the logical expression for data filtration is like below:

// code sample : use input_row to define the condition.
// input_row.columnName1.equals("foo") ||!(input_row.columnName2.equals("bar"))

```
(!(row3.one_GRP_NM == null && row3.two_GRP_NM == null) && 
 !(row3.one_GRP_NM != null && row3.one_GRP_NM.equals(row3.two_GRP_NM)))
```

Now I converted into below -

```
df[((((df['one_grp_nm']=='null') & (df['two_grp_nm']=='null')) &
     ((df['one_grp_nm']!='null') & (df['one_grp_nm']==df['two_grp_nm'])))]
```

But I am not able to figure it out how to convert the ! expression at the beginning of the logic. Could you please guide how to implement not matching/not in in pandas df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, negation (i.e. not) is denoted using a `~`

For your application, it should be :

```
df[((~((df['one_grp_nm']=='null') & (df['two_grp_nm']=='null')) &\
     ~((df['one_grp_nm']!='null') & (df['one_grp_nm']==df['two_grp_nm']))))]
```

Note that if you are breaking across line after `&`, you should add a backslash `\` otherwise it will be a syntax error.

Another example on `not in` in Pandas:

```
match = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

# Note the ~
# You can read it as `not (isin)`
df[~df['col_1'].isin(match)]
```

will give you:

```
    col_1
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks lot for your help. Looks like I need to modify little bit for the null column as well ->

```
df[(~((df['one_grp_nm'].isnull()) & (df['two_grp_nm'].isnull())) &\
    ~(((df['one_grp_nm'].notna()) & (df['one_grp_nm']==df['two_grp_nm'])))
  )]
```